# Can ext2fsd be used to turn a volume as NTFS?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, ext4, ext3

I have a ext4 formatted hard drive. Could I plug it into my Windows system using `ext2fsd`, and turn it into NTFS using the following steps?

- Plug `ext4` formatted drive into Windows using `ext2fsd`.
- Deallocate the free space
- Format the free space as NTFS
- Copy everything from the `ext4` partition to the `NTFS` one.
- Format the `ext4` partition as `NTFS`
- Join them both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do that if I were you.  For a filesystem you should use the tools of the os for which it was created.  These cross-over tools often don't work as well as you might wish.

I am gathering you only have one drive?  If so, then my best suggestion, assuming your data takes up less than half the drive, is:

1. using a live dvd of ubuntu, say, resize down the ext4 partition (meaning resize the filesystem in the partition)
2. create a new empty (unformatted) partition in the empty space
3. create and save checksums (sha256 or so) of every file in the filesystem
4. using windows now, create an ntfs partition in the new partition
5. crossing your fingers, on windows use ext2fsd to copy from the ext4 to the ntfs.
6. using windows, create checksums of every file in the ntfs partition
7. compare them and make sure nothing is fubar.
8. assuming not, you can go back to ubuntu and delete the ext4 partition
9. i don't know if windows give you a way to resize an NTFS partition (meaning resize the NTFS filesystem in the partition).  if not, you'll have space left over.

Notice that #1, #5 and #9 are not without risk.  Since you are not working with a backup, always a bad idea, I'll wish you good luck.

Comment: «if windows give you a way to resize an NTFS partition» Yes, it does. It can also be done with Gparted on a Linux system.

Comment: It should have more properly been stated, "if windows gives you a way to resize an NTFS filesystem".  That I wouldn't do with linux tools.